# CachingSessionFactory setPoolSize() takes much longer after upgrading spring boot from 2.2.1.RELEASE to 2.3.1.Release

Tags: java, spring-boot, ftp

In one of our services, we use spring integration framework to send some files to an FTP server. For that, we create a CachingSessionFactory in the following way

```
SessionFactory<?> factory = getSessionFactory(properties);
CachingSessionFactory cachingSessionFactory = new CachingSessionFactory<>(factory);
cachingSessionFactory.setSessionWaitTimeout(properties.getTimeout());
cachingSessionFactory.setPoolSize(5);
createDirectories(cachingSessionFactory, properties);
```

properties are some @ConfigurationProperties that we inject and was created by us. GetSessionFactory() is also done by us, but I'm not sure it this is relevant.

After we updated from spring boot 2.2.1.Release to 2.3.1.Release we have a huge performance penalty on service startup.
It looks like there is an issue with setting the pool size, but I cannot figure out what it is. When debugging, I see that the process hangs forever in the setPoolSize(5) step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I digged a little into the underlying classes and found out that the setPoolSize() is heavier than expected. Especially, it needs to acquire some locking which, in my case, seems to cause the performance penalty. I didn't find the actual root cause, but I have a convenient way to overcome the issue by setting the pool size directly via the constructor. By that, it is created correctly and no messing with the existing one is needed. This line did the trick

```
CachingSessionFactory cachingSessionFactory = new CachingSessionFactory<>(factory,5);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try using - `DefaultFtpSessionFactory` instead of `CachingSessionFactory`
`DefaultFtpSessionFactory` doesn't need that pool to work.